# Criando tabuleiro 2d com imagens

Tags: jquery, 2d

Olá,
Estou criando um jogo de tabuleiro2d com Js/html/CSS,

Com o código abaixo consigo fazer com que o texto de cada div se movimente pelo tabuleiro, mas não consigo fazer com que essas peças sejam imagens...

No codepen abaixo consegue visualizar com o funcionamento atual:
https://codepen.io/luizpicolo/pen/hArIt

..Abaixo vou colocar o js que gostaria de modificar para que aceitasse imagem no lugar de caracteres a serem movimentados:

```
// Função para realizar as jogas
$('#container div.row div').click(function(){

   // Captura o ID da posição da peça
   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   // Captura o conteudo da seleção (Imagem peça)
   var peca = $(this).text();

   // inclui a peça seleciona no WebStoraged utilizando a   função setPosicaoPeca. Caso a peça já esteja selecionada anteriormente, a mesma e posicionada no local desejada e é limpada do webStoraged
   if (peca != ""){
      setPosicaoPeca(id, peca);
      $(this).text("");
   }
   else {
      if (getPeca()){
         $('#'+id).text(getPeca());

            // Altera o contador de movimentos
            $('#pontuacao').text(
              parseInt($('#pontuacao').text()) + 1
            );

         // funcao para limpar os dados
         limparDados();
      }
   }
})

// Função para setar a posição da peça e salvar no webstoraged
function setPosicaoPeca(id, peca) {
  localStorage.setItem("id", id);
  localStorage.setItem("peca", peca);
}

// Função para retornar o ID da peça que havia sido selecionada anteriormente
function getPosicaoID() {
  return localStorage.getItem("id");
}

// Função para o retorno da peca selecionada anteriormente
function getPeca() {
  return localStorage.getItem('peca');
}

// Função para limpar todos os dados 
function limparDados() {
  localStorage.clear();
}

// Função para validar os dados da jogada
function validarJogada(posicaoInicial, posicaFinal, peca)
{
  // Cavalo preto
  if (peca == '&#9816') 
  {
    if (!(posicaoInicial - posicaFinal) == 17)
    {
      alert("Jogada Inválida");
    }
  }
}
```

Como poderia fazer?

Comment: você diz, alterar isso? var peca = $(this).text();

Comment: sim isso mesmo, tem esse trecho para implementar: var peca = $(this).text() ...e tbm outros... como esse: $('#'+id).text(getPeca());

Comment: e no html, em cada id como esse:   <div id="1">&#9814</div>.. quero inserir uma imagem como por exemplo: <div id="1"><img src="imgs/user.ico" width="50px" height="50px" /></div>

Comment: eu não sei se a melhor forma vai ser você manipular as imagens, talvez seja mais interessante por classe (já que algumas imagens se repetem). 
Com a imagem, voce poderia usar $(this).find('img').attr("src"); para localizar a imagem selecionada

Comment: Nesse exemplo está com peças de xadrez, mas preciso ter a possibilidade de usar imagens aleatórias de outras coisas, ou icones de classe como fontawesome, pq vou fazer um recurso de outro segmento q não é o xadrez,

Comment: tentei assim: var peca = $(this).find('img').attr("src");.....$('#'+id).find('img').attr("src").text(getPeca());... mas não deu certo

Comment: criei um codepen nesse momento para podermos exemplificar e testar melhor o teste com as imagens... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWJdvw

Comment: vc poderia salvar a alteração nesse link e enviar aqui para visualizarmos?

Comment: nesse link adicionei uma imagem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWJdvw

Comment: tentei tbm $(this).find('img'); mas não foi

Comment: olá.. ainda não consegui.. alguma idéia..?

Comment: ..ainda não consegui... Alguém sabe como implementar a imagem ou icone nesse js/html e serem movimentados com o clique?

codepen.io/anon/pen/xWJdvw

Comment: Olá, criei um chat referente esse assunto: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77708/tabuleiro-interativo-jquery-css-html-como-fazer